# How can I obfuscate bindPassword in ldap.config of JAAS in Jetty?

Tags: ldap, passwords, jetty, obfuscation, jaas

I have a working configuration of LDAP authentication on Jetty 8 / OpenLDAP. 
Due to security consideration I have to obfuscate cleantext passwords in config files.

Upto now I could not find a way to do it in ldap.config file for LdapLoginModule of  java.security.auth.login.config regarding bindPassword property. 
Is it possible to do so some standard or jetty-provided way eg: like with org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password obfuscator - or should I implement a specific LdapLoginModule to do so?

Relating config entries:

```
    web.xml:
    ...
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>MY JAAS Realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>access-denied.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>   
    ... 

    jetty-web.xml:
    ...
    <Set name="securityHandler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
            <Set name="loginService">
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
                    <Set name="name">MY JAAS Realm</Set>
                    <Set name="loginModuleName">LdapLoginModule</Set>
                </New>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>


    ldap.config:

    LdapLoginModule {
       org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
       debug="true"
       debugNative="true"
       contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
       hostname="127.0.0.1"
       port="389"
       bindDn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
       bindPassword="___cleantext_password_I_want_to_obfuscate___"
       ...


    Java commandline parameter:
      -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/fullpath/of/ldap.config
```

Comment: The usual solution to this sort of thing is physical security of the server: smart card access and so on.

Comment: Thanks - good idea, however I have to respond to the "new wave approaches" as we are designing a cloud-like solution whereon the possibilities of applying physical restrictions are limited. On the other hand obfuscation is also not rock-solid crypto solution but could only server as a 1st line barrier.